# Azure DevOps Services RestAPI 7.1 Pull Requests - Get Pull Requests

Tags: azure, rest, devops, pull-request, azure-rest-api

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-requests?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#gitpullrequest) the GitPullRequest object should have a property called commits which is an array of GitCommitRef.  Every time I hit the end point, I'm not getting this property.  Is there something I should set to get this, or is the documentation wrong?

Comment: You can get the commit related data using `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/commits?api-version=7.0`, if you have any commits

Comment: Id rather not make a call for every PR to get the list of commits.  We release almost daily so our PR's are relatively small.

Answer (score 0):

> GetPullRequest object should have a property called commits which is an array of GitCommitRef. Every time I hit the end point, I'm not getting this property.

Please ensure, you have commits in your pull request. If you do then you will also get `GitCommitRef properties like commitId, _links, url etc.` in the response of your Get call.

I am getting all the properties which are mentioned in this [ms sample response body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-requests?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#pull-requests-by-repository) like below-

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There are commits in the PR.

Comment: If you have commits then you will be able to see them like I am able to see in my response body

Comment: Your response body in the image above has `lastMergeSourceCommit`, `lastMergeTargetCommit`, `lastMergeCommit`, but not a property called `commits` which, as the docs say, should be an array of Commits

Comment: I believe you are referring to gitcommitref property, refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-requests?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#gitcommitref, it has listed all the metadata in this property and in my response body all the mera data are there

Answer (score 0):

According to these docs, that property is not defined in the response. I would file an issue with their docs team and verify if that property was deprecated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-requests?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by "According to these docs, that property is not defined in the response."  The docs say there should be a property called "commits".  I agree that maybe it was removed and the docs should be updated.

Comment: The response payload doesn't have a `commits` property.

Comment: The docs clearly say that there should be a `commits` property in the response payload https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-requests?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#gitpullrequest

Comment: where do you see that?  in the link I gave, the only related properties are `lastMergeSourceCommit` `lastMergeTargetCommit` `lastMergeCommit`, which none of those are equivalent to an array of `GitCommitRef` per the OP question

Comment: Did you click the link I posted? It seems like you are only looking at the sample response and not looking at the table that defines that a response should be an array of GitPullRequest. which is what I linked and has a commits property

Comment: Ah, right. My mistake. I see it now